# How to boot to a user in windows 8.1 but with a locked screen

Tags: windows, boot, lock-screen

I have a windows 8.1 computer with multiple users which I remotely use via team viewer. I find that from time to time the computer reboots and goes to the lock screen. The issue is that my main user account has not started so I can't access the services I would like to. On the other hand the computer is in a office and I wouldn't want it to boot to the desktop with out password.

Can I somehow automatically start a user at boot but keep it locked?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of logging in, you can make it so that TeamViewer starts at boot, så that when you connect, you see the locked screen, and can unlock it!

Open teamviewer and set up "Unattended access", and make sure it is set to start as a service in the settings(Should be set then unattended access is enabled)

It can be set up here:
Connection - Set up unattended access.

If that doesn't work go to "Extra - Settings - General" and make sure "Start TeamViewer with Windows is ticked.

Comment: Thanks ill give it a shot, the only issue is that the my network connection is a bit odd and may require me to be logged in.

Comment: After checking, unfortunately I have these setting on already, and the problem persists.

Comment: Hmm.. Then I¨'m afraid I don't know anything.. Maybe put a script that locks the computer to be executed 30 seconds after boot?